# range operator not returning expected results via mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I've now tested this via the shell, Studio 3T IDE and within my API itself.

The first query looks something like this:

```
Notification.find({
  userId: ObjectId("...")
}).limit(20).sort('-createdAt')
```

which returns the following documents sorted by their `createdAt` timestamp (which is also imbedded in the `_id` field):

[image]

I then run the next query which I would expect to return the results starting at `_id: ObjectId("615869eac849ec00205aa112")`:

```
Notification.find({
  userId: ObjectId("..."),
  _id: { $lt: ObjectId("615869eac849ec00205aa115"}
}).limit(20).sort('-createdAt')
```

I would expect this command to get me my next 20 results sorted in the same descending order as the original query above.  However, I get the following:

[image]

which has 3 results from the original query.  The `_id` field is clearly unique between the `_id` I use as a cursor and the incorrectly returned results but after inspection the `createdAt` timestamp is the exact same as the `createdAt` timestamp of the document `_id` I use for the range query.

Comment: maybe this can help: sort({$natural:-1})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are querying on an unsorted field expecting that value to identify a specific point the result set.

Note that in the first result set entries 17 through 29 all have the same epoch timestamp in the _id value, and that those 13 entries are not in any particular order.

As luck would have it, entry 20 has the greatest _id of that group, so all 12 of the others are lesser, even the ones that happened to come before.

To make this work, also sort on _id like:

```
.sort({createdAt: -1, _id: -1})
```